# How to get ints out of dictionary keys in python that are string type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary in python. The entire contents of the dictionary are strings, however some of the keys are ints. I need to be able to get the keys and values that are integers.

Example:

```py
dictionary_in_question = {"name" : "Value", "1":"1.3"}
```

I need to get the dictionary entry that is `{"1":"1.3"}` and put it in a new dictionary

There are no current build errors, I just need the data in a new dictionary and have no idea how to go about getting it there.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use [`.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) to check if each key is numeric

- This method uses a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```py
my_dict = {"name" : "Value", "1":"1.3"}

num_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k.isnumeric()}

print(num_dict)

>>> {'1': '1.3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `str.isdigit()`

```py
dictionary_in_question = {"name" : "Value", "1":"1.3"}
new_dict = {}
for k,v in dictionary_in_question.items():
     if k.isdigit() or v.isdigit():
         new_dict[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to see if all characters of a string are digits:

```
{int(k): float(v) for (k,v) in dictionary_in_question.items() if k.isdigit()}
```

Prints:

```
{1: 1.3}
```

In case you need the value as integer as well, you can convert the value by `int(float(v))`